# ElasticSearch snapshot leaving snapshot indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Please could someone explain what 'snapshot' indexes are, and what should be done to make my ES cluster be green again? What I've been doing to encounter these is this:

I'm creating a snapshot of an old ElasticSearch cluster that is still running 1.3.4.

I've setup a file system repository and then attempted to create a snapshot with:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9900/snapshot/es_hot_backup/snapshot_1'
```

However that gave an error:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]","status":400}
```

Running the command again with 'ignore_unavailable' set, like this:

```
curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9900/_snapshot/es_hot_backup/snapshot_1" -d '{
     "ignore_unavailable": true
}'
```

The command appears to have worked

```
{"accepted":true}
```

However now the status of the cluster is no longer green, as it appears that a 'snapshot' index has been created, but in a way that means it is not replicated across the cluster:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9900/_cat/shards?v


index    shard prirep state      docs store ip         node         
snapshot 2     p      STARTED       0  115b 172.18.0.2 Space Turnip 
snapshot 2     r      UNASSIGNED                                    
snapshot 0     p      STARTED       0  115b 172.18.0.2 Space Turnip 
snapshot 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                    
snapshot 3     p      STARTED       0  115b 172.18.0.2 Space Turnip 
snapshot 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                    
snapshot 1     p      STARTED       0  115b 172.18.0.2 Space Turnip 
snapshot 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                    
snapshot 4     p      STARTED       0  115b 172.18.0.2 Space Turnip 
snapshot 4     r      UNASSIGNED
```

(I initially started running the snapshot on production, but switched to a test environment once the initial snapshot command gave a weird error. Yes, I should have done it in test from the start. :p).

Please can someone advise what should I do with that non-replicated index, so as to make the ElasticSearch cluster be green again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command was wrong: there is no `snapshot` endpoint, but a `_snapshot` one (notice the underscore). And when you added the `ignore_unavailable` option you also changed the endpoint to the correct one. Using the unknown `snapshot` endpoint you just told ES to create a `snapshot` index.

At this point you can safely delete the `snapshot` index.